# How to create a byte array with ints, strings, and others

Tags: objective-c, arrays, byte

I need to create a byte array. I have 10 values (ints, strings, and others), and I need to save in an array to return to another method to send trough a socket.

1. I have to convert the String or int to byte
2. In some situations, I have to use a mask, for example: `((lenghtPack & 0xFF) >> 8)`
3. I have to save the byte into an array.

I need some help, because I tried with `NSData`, `NSMutablearray`, but I can't make work.

Can somebody tell me what is the best way and how to do? Thanks.

Comment: What does the other end expect?  Do you have a specification?  (Note that you can easily create a `byte[]` array -- you don't need anything fancier in many cases.  If not that then you probably should use an `NSMutableArray` -- if you should be using a byte array at all.)  (Why not JSON?)

Comment: I'm translating a Android/Java code, so I try to use something similar.
I have to send a byte array to the other side.
I have to put Vars inside the byte array, so i need a mutable array
I tried with NSMutableArray, but addObject need and object and byte is not and object. How I solve?
Thanks

Comment: Oops, I meant to say `NSMutableData`, not `NSMutableArray`.  [`NSMutableData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html) is essentially a variable-length array of byte.

Comment: Yes, I also try with NSMutableData, but I don't know how add something like this: (lenghtPack & 0xFF) on this method: [dataByte appendBytes:<#(const void *)#> length:<#(NSUInteger)#>]; 
How i made the conversion?? Thanks

Comment: Store into a (fixed-length) temp `byte` array and then pass the array as the `appendBytes:` parm.

Comment: `byte temp[10];  temp[0] = lengthPack & 0xFF;  [mutableDataObject appendBytes:temp length:1];`

Comment: I tested and It works, but why I have to use Byte temp[1]; and temp[0] = lenghtPack & 0xFF; and Not Byte temp = lenghtPack & 0xFF; ??? If I use the last ones, when I do [dataByte appendBytes:temp length:1]; "crashed"

Comment: `byte temp;` will work if you do `appendBytes:&temp`.  Remember, this is basically C, where an array name is kinda like a pointer.  But using a byte array will let you "buffer up" several bytes of data before appending -- a hair more efficient and less "cluttered".

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks it works great!!